# android add safe-args classpath in new Gragle Plugin versions

Tags: android, android-safe-args

How can I solve this problem?
**Navigation classes are not generated**

I created a new project with the `new gradle structure` but I can't use `navigation` because I don't know where to add it.

[image: 1]

Comment: check on app.gradle

Comment: also i added "androidx.navigation.safeargs" plugin but not found this plugin